Assign maxsize for disk space using shell scrip
I want to create a script whereby I need to assign the MAXAVAILSIZE of disk space. And, when the Avail size is greater than or equal to the MAXAVAILSIZE, it will gzip the log files.
Example:
Filesystem                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                                  20G   4.0K   16G   89% /secrets/gateway-public

MAXAVAILSIZE=16G
AVAILSIZE=`findmnt -no Avail /secrets/gateway-public`

echo "MAXAVAILSIZE is $MAXAVAILSIZE"
echo "AVAILSIZE is $AVAILSIZE"

if [ "${AVAILSIZE}" -ge "${MAXAVAILSIZE}" ]; then
  echo "mounted"
  gzip test_202401*
else
  echo "not mounted"
fi

Every time I run this script the value of avail size that I am getting is 15.7G which is not the same as the one shown when I use the df -h.
Also, I am getting this error line 64: [: 15.7G: integer expression expected in this part:
if [ "${AVAILSIZE}" -ge "${MAXAVAILSIZE}" ]; then

May I know how do I resolve this?

The error message clearly says what is wrong. 15.7G is not an integer number, as well as 16G. You can't compare them with -ge operator.

Values are not the same because different utilites use different format and precision for output. To get integer number of available 1k blocks you can use, for example, AVAILSIZE=$(df -k --output=avail /secrets/gateway-public | tail -n 1)

I do not understand the logic of [ "$AVAILSIZE" -ge "$MAXAVAILSIZE" ] && gzip test_202401*. Why would you compress the files when there's more space available than the threshold? Also, why do those files seem unrelated to the mounting-point?

@Fravadona, our server on this mountpoint always get disk space full. Our resolution is to compressed some of the log files. Instead of manually checking the df -h and compressing the file. I was thinking to create a script, so if the avail space size reach this certain size, it shld auto gzip the log files.

Given your explanations, the condition for triggering the compression is wrong; you should test that the available space is less than 16GB.
Also, floating-point arithmetic is not standard in the shell, so you should get rid of "human-readeable" sizes and use whole numbers with smaller units.
Here's what I would do:
mountpoint=/secrets/gateway-public

minavailsize=$((16*1000*1000*1000/1024)) # 16GB expressed in KiB

availsize=$(df -kP "$mountpoint" | awk 'NR == 2 {print $4}')

if [ -z "${availsize:+1}" ] # the output of df was empty
then
    echo "not mounted"
else
    echo "mounted"
    [ "$availsize" -lt "$minavailsize" ] && gzip "$mountpoint"/test_202401*
fi


May I ask question about this [ "$availsize" -lt "$minavailsize" ] && gzip "$mountpoint"/test_202401*? Is this an if condition? if the availsize is less than the minavailsize then it will gzip?
